# How to iterate the values to create multiple json strings of struct type and store in dataframe using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Not able to generate multiple json string in one column value and store it in dataframe column as struct type with below mentioned schema

Input table data is of string type:

| Data |
| --- |
| [{'"col3"': '155350','"col1"': '144399','"col2"': '10951'},{'"col3"': '155350','"col1"': '144399','"col2"': '10951'}] |
| [{'"col3"': '155350','"col1"': '144399','"col2"': '10951'} |
| Null |

Expected dataframe output as struct type with below schema as datatype:

schema = StructType([StructField('Name',ArrayType(StructType([StructField('col1',LongType(),True),StructField('Col2',LongType(),True), StructField('col3',LongType(),True)]),True),True)])

Expect output:

| Data |
| --- |
| [{'col1': '155350','col2': '144399','col3': '10951'},{'col1': '155350', 'col2': '144399','col3': '10951'}] |
| [{'col1': '155350','col2': '144399','col3': '10951'} |
| [{'col1': '155350','col2': '144399','col3': '10951'}] |